# How to imbed the irrational rotation algebra into AF algebra?

Tags: reference-request, c-star-algebras

I'am reading Kenneth R.Davidson`s book C*-Algebras by Example. I feel confused by the construction of embedding irrational rotation algebra into associated AF algebra, Is there another book give a detailed description?

Comment: I don't know about a book, but the remarks at the end of the chapter in Davidson's book gives references to two papers where this construction occurs:  The original by Pimsner and Voiculescu, and a paper of Davidson.